# linear spline interpolation error plot with python

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I tried to implement the scipy linear spline interpolation and found its error, but when I plot the error in log base 10 versus the interval between each point in log base 10, I got every other point working fine but the last few points being really weird. I couldn't figure out what I did wrong. Can someone look at my code and just save my life from staring at the last three points please?

```
def f(x):
    return 2*(3*x**2 -1)/(x**2 +1)**3
def error(x, y, h):
    size = len(x)
    error = 0
    if (size == 2):
        return 2.362186149
    for i in range(0, size - 1):
        lower_bound = x[i]
        upper_bound = x[i+1]
        max_z = abs(opt.fminbound(lambda x: -f(x), lower_bound,upper_bound))
        err = max_z *h**2 /8
        error = error + err
    return error
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    start = -5
    end = 5
    n = np.linspace(1, 50, 50)
    arr = []
    hr = []
    for each in n:
        x = np.linspace(start, end, each + 1)
        y = np.reciprocal(np.array(np.square(x) + 1))
        h = float(end - start) / each
        arr.append(abs(error(x, y, h)))
        hr.append(h)
    log = np.log10(arr)
    hlog = np.log10(hr)
    plt.scatter(hlog, log)
    plt.plot(hlog, log)
    plt.title("log of error vs log h")
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "last few points being really weird" what were you expecting?

Comment: Like when x  is  1 and 0.75,  the graph suddenly changed.Before  that, the graph was  almost linear